Tell Flowtype to read files before analysis
Working in a vanilla JS project (NOT the vanilla framework), it would be nice to be able to preload some JS files before analyzing the "main" file you want to check. Is this possible? Or do I have to write manual declare-files?
I tried with [include] and [declaration] in the flowconfig, but without success.
